# Update model inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

How do you update a model with array of objects inside ngFor? My code ignores all updates.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of model.items; let i = index">
  <input name="names-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.name" class="input" type="text">
  <input name="values-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value" class="input" type="text">
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
model.items = [{ name: ... value: ...}, { name: ... value: ...}, ...]
```

Comment: It works for me. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbjx5a).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `markForCheck()` method for updating the model if it does not change when the data changes.